# Adding Videos to a Magento 2 product using REST

Tags: rest, api, magento, magento2.2

Magento version 2.2.5
Endpoint in question /V1/products/{sku}/media METHOD: POST

I am trying to add a video under a product sku using Magento's provided API endpoint.

```
{
 "entry": {
     "media_type": "external-video",
     "label": "Video 2",
     "position": 2,
     "disabled": false,
     "types": ["thumbnail"],
     "content" : {
         "base64_encoded_data": "encoded image data ",
         "type": "image/jpeg",
         "name": "0.jpg"
     },
     "extension_attributes": {
         "video_content": {
             "media_type": "external-video",
             "video_provider": "youtube",
             "video_url": "some youtube video url",
             "video_title": "some title",
             "video_description": "",
             "video_metadata": ""
         }
     }
}
```

The response I get from this call is "invalid option value", I had debugged this in a local environment which leads me to failure during ProductRepository->save() within Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\GalleryGalleryManagement.php on line 70.

Is this an issue with my payload or actual magento bug?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by adding videos directly using POST /V1/products or PUT /V1/products/{sku} endpoints.

post method example:

```
{ 
  "product": {
     "sku": "some-sku",
     ..... other product data,
     "media_gallery_entries": {
         "media_type": "external-video",
         "label": "Video 2",
         "position": 2,
         "disabled": false,
         "types": [],
         "content" : {
             "base64_encoded_data": "encoded image data ",
             "type": "image/jpeg",
             "name": "0.jpg"
          },
          "extension_attributes": {
              "video_content": {
                  "media_type": "external-video",
                  "video_provider": "youtube",
                  "video_url": "some youtube video url",
                  "video_title": "some title",
                  "video_description": "",
                  "video_metadata": ""
          }
     }
   }
}
```

I had no luck with Magento's MediaGallery POST endpoint (/V1/products/{sku}/media.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a video to the product page then why you did not try using YouTube API?

You just need to follow these steps:

- Generate a YouTube API Key by going goodle developer console
- Then add Youtube API key to your Magento 2 by going to STORES --> Configuration
- Then Add Video URL